# jMeter parse gzipped response xml

Tags: jmeter

As part of my jMeter scenario, I got gzipped xml from server. 
I've tried to add header  Accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch but it seems to have no effect.

How can I deflate it in order to use XPath extractor on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about how to convert gzip-compressed response to plain XML, it can be done using [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor)

Beanshell PostProcessor execution time is not included into parent sampler response time. It is executed after sampler and in your case can be used to decompress response and substitute parent sampler's response body with decompressed XML.

Sample code for the Beanshell PostProcessor:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gis);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
byte[] decompressed = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
prev.setResponseData(decompressed);
```

where

- `data` - is a shorthand to byte array containing parent sampler response body
- `prev` - represents [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) instance access, SampleResult provides read/write access to information recorded during sampler execution.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter, detailed explanation of pre-defined variables like "data" or "prev" and some useful examples.